# How to change the gradient color of a jquery mobile listview?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I want to change the gradient color of a listview to a custom color.  Thanks!

```
<div class="content">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please spend a little time researching this and coming up with a solution on your own.  A simple search on the web will yield up the answer to this trivial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  The css below will work with any browser.  The second hex is the top, the first hex is the bottom of the gradient.

```
.color_tabs li a {
background-color: #00B6CF !important;
background-repeat: repeat-x !important;
/* fallback */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#009DB2), to(#00B6CF)) !important;
/* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #009DB2, #00B6CF) !important;
/* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #009DB2, #00B6CF) !important;
/* Firefox 3.6+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #009DB2, #00B6CF) !important;
/* IE 10 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #009DB2, #00B6CF) !important;
/* Opera 11.10+ */
color:#FFFFFF !important;
text-shadow:rgb(0, 0, 0) 0.08em 0.08em 0px !important;
border-bottom-width:1px !important;
border-bottom-color:#201F23 !important;
}
```

and add the class "color_tabs" to your ul.

```
<div class="content">
<ul data-role="listview" class="color_tabs">
    <li><a href="#">One</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Five</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have attached a jsfiddle with a hover example http://jsfiddle.net/22e998fx/

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted thank you!  Why !important on each css?

Comment: With jqm i always use !important to override any jqm classes.  It isnt always necessary.